# UIAlertView enter Apple ID and Password IAP

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, uialertview

When I start test my IAP the system requests me apple id and password. There is an alert view with ok and cancel buttons.

I need to handle this button, because when I press on cancel button I need to make some action  in app.

Very important: there is an autorize dialog not a purchase alert. I need to know how to process this action in app (for example if user tap on cancel button and after this autorize dialog disappear)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you see only an authorize alert, not a purchase alert, that means you are trying to restore purchases.

If user taps on cancel button on authorize dialog, this delegate method gets called:

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Comment: tnx for response, but i mean not about purchase aletr i mean about alert that request my Apple ID and password

Comment: that's what i'm talking about. "alert that request your Apple ID and password" is not purchase alert. it is restore dialog.

Comment: This worked really well for me, but is there any specific 'cleanup' you have to implement in restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError?

Answer (score 3):

You have to handle this case in failedTransaction delegate message:

```
- (void)failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled)
    {
        // error!
    }
    else
    {
        // this is fine, the user just cancelled
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but there is soursces don't cancel autorized dialog (alert view). it cancel purchase

Comment: as I wrote above. I need to handle the dialogue authorization

Comment: your example shows how to handle transaction, but in my case this is just have to handle dialog that request apple id and password in app

Comment: In the Guide "SKPaymentQueue - The payment queue is used to communicate with the App Store. When payments are added to the queue, Store Kit transmits the request to the App Store. Store Kit presents dialogs to ask the user to authorize payment. The completed transaction is returned to your application’s observer." So a cancel in the dialog is handled by the -failedTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction delegate.